# Php code to import excel file to database

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to import Excel data to my database using PHPExcel. Below is my code.

When I upload the excel file and submit the form, I can echo out the table but no data is being stored in the database, Can anyone please help me with this. Something is wrong with the SQL part or creating array of the data. Please anyone check and help me out. I can't use csv file, otherwise it would have been easier.

ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use, tag, image, link) VALUES ('NULL', 'Silk 18', 'Silk 18', 'Machine Made', '1' at line 1

```
<?php
/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION START HERE   ****************************/


# Database Connection
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ron143', 'tcc') OR die('Error: '.mysqli_connect_error());


/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION END HERE  ****************************/


/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

# Upload the file to server
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$target_dir = "../../temp/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($file);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
$xls_url = "$target_dir$file";

// This is the file info to be uploaded.
$inputFileName = $xls_url;
$inputFileType = $_POST['file_type'];
$sheetname = '0'; /** input the worksheet number to read. 0 for first and 1 for second worksheet */

try {

    /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

    /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data and not its formating or any formula set on it **/
    #$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

} catch(Exception $e) {

    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());

}

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet($sheetname)->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet
 echo $arrayCount;

for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
$product_name = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
$product_code = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
$category1 = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);
$category1_id = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]);
$category2 = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]);
$category2_id = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["F"]);
$stylename = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]);
$grams = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["H"]);
$thickness = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["I"]);
$width = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["J"]);
$length = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["K"]);
$color_ground = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["L"]);
$color_border = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["M"]);
$material = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["N"]);
$backing = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["O"]);
$reed = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["P"]);
$weave = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["Q"]);
$ply = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["R"]);
$pile = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["S"]);
$care = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["T"]);
$precaution = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["U"]);
$use = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["V"]);
$tag = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["W"]);
$image = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["X"]);
$link = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["Y"]);


$query = "SELECT product_code FROM products WHERE product_code = '".$product_code."'";
$sql = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$recResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$existCode = $recResult["product_code"];

$q = "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, product_code, category1, category1_id, category2, category2_id, stylename, grams, thickness, width, length, color_ground, color_border, material, backing, reed, weave, ply, pile, care, precaution, use, tag, image, link)
VALUES ('NULL', '".$product_name."', '".$product_code."', '".$category1."', '".$category1_id."', '".$category2."', '".$category2_id."', '".$stylename."', '".$grams."', '".$thickness."', '".$width."', '".$length."', '".$color_ground."', '".$color_border."', '".$material."', '".$backing."', '".$reed."', '".$weave."', '".$ply."', '".$pile."', '".$care."', '".$precaution."', '".$use."', '".$tag."', '".$image."', '".$link."')";

     if (mysqli_query($dbc, $q)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $q . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbc);
}


}

echo "<div style='font: bold 18px arial,verdana;padding: 45px 0 0 500px;'>".$msg."</div>";

?>
```

Comment: `if($q != '' )` - I don't see `$q` being set before, so, `$q` is empty.

Comment: @PedroLobito He's technically defining $q in the previous if statement. Because of PHP's weird scoping rules, the set $q will be available in the next conditional. However, I think this is still bad practice. OP, what does http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php tell you?

Comment: i am not getting any sql error..... canot figure out what is wrong....it should import the data....but it is not

Comment: 'NULL' which you use for column `product_id` is not a SQL NULL , but rather a string saying "NULL". Are you sure this is what you wanted?
Also: constructing the query by concatenating strings is probably the worst way to do it. Why don't you use mysqli prepared statements? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @murison ok i will remove it but is there any syntax error on the statement

Comment: well - if the column would be an integer , and you try to put a string there - sure it may cause an error ;)
I strongly advise to change your code so you use prepared statement. or at least escape the variables you put in your query string (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). What if one of them contains a apostrohe (" ' ") ? answer that yourself

Comment: @murison im will use prepared statement, thanks for the assistance, and i have figured out the problem. its something to do with the use column in the database. i changed the name to product_use and its working fine. thanks for the help

Comment: check your code's behaviour, when you have an apostrophe in some cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better save your excell file as a csv file and parsing it with php without using any other library.

- Use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php): for getting one line of a file
- Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php): to break a csv file line into an array.

Comment: i am getting the data displayed nicely on the page. but why can't I get the data stored on my database? can you please help check the sql part of the code?

Comment: try to replace this 'NULL' by NULL! NULL is not a string but a constant.

Comment: I have figured it out. its something to do with the use column in the database. i changed its name to product_use and its working fine